# Testing Vuetify v-checkbox with Vue test utils 2 - wrapper.setValue() cannot be called on V-CHECKBOX

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I am trying call `setValue` on a Vuetify checkbox in a Jest test.

```
it('checks "Select All" when all items are selected', async () => {
        const checkboxes = wrapper.findAll('.enable-item-checkbox');
        const checkboxA = wrapper.find('.checkboxA')
        const selectAllCheckbox = checkboxes.at(0)

        expect(selectAllCheckbox.attributes('checked')).toBeFalsy();
        expect(checkboxA.attributes('checked')).toBe('false');

        await checkboxA.setValue(true);

        expect(checkboxA.attributes('checked')).toBeTruthy();
        expect(selectAllCheckbox.attributes('checked')).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

I am on Vue 3 and Vue test utils 2. This is the Vuetify element

```
<div class="mr-25" v-for="items in items" :key="provider" style="display: inline-block">
   <v-checkbox
     :value="item"
     v-model="selectedItems"
     :checked="isSelected(items)"
     class="enable-item-checkbox"
     :class="{ [`${item}`]: true }"
   ></v-checkbox>
</div>
```

I added setup.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
```

and changed the test script in package.json to look like this

`"test": "jest --require ./src/tests/setup.js"`

I am getting error

> wrapper.setValue() cannot be called on V-CHECKBOX

I am using `mount` and not `shallowmount`.

What is the correct way to set this?

I have tried using setChecked.
I have tried adding `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();` after setValue
I have tried using .trigger('click'); and .trigger('change');

None of the above worked

I tried looking on the GitHub issues for Vuetify and Vue test utils but found no open or closed issues matching this

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```js
const checkboxA = wrapper.find('.checkboxA').get('input')
checkboxA.setChecked()
```

or you could attach a test specific attribute like `data-test` and it seems the attribute will be appended directly to the input tag so you could do:

```js
const checkboxA = wrapper.find('[data-test="checkboxA"]')
checkboxA.setChecked()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. your first suggestion gave me this error

`Unable to get input within: <v-checkbox data-test="Azure AD" modelvalue="Okta,Ping,COGNITO" checked="false" class="enable-provider-checkbox Azure AD" label="Azure AD" value="Azure AD"></v-checkbox>`

your second suggestion didn't give an error but it didn't update the checkbox.

Comment: are you sure you are mounting (not shallowmount) the component? what happens when you do:

`console.log(checkboxA.html())`

Comment: 100% sure I am using mount. When I console log, I get this
`<v-checkbox data-test="checkboxA" modelvalue="checkboxB,checkboxC,checkboxD" checked="false" class="enable-provider-checkbox checkboxA" label="checkboxA" value="checkboxA"></v-checkbox>`. You can still see `checked="false"`

Comment: when you mount instead of shallow mount, you should see it log the underlying html tags produced, not `v-checkbox`, this might be an issue with the setup of the unit testing for Vuetify 3. Not sure if this helps but this shows how to setup tests for Vuetify 2 https://medium.com/@d007dav/how-to-test-your-vuetify-project-with-jest-vue-test-utils-and-vue-cli-step-by-step-guide-da22347f2343

Comment: I didn't have the setup.js file before. I added it and I am still not seeing the underlying HTML tags